# SharePoint 2013 workflow fails to assign a task for username with single quote (apostrophe)

Tags: 2013, workflow, active-directory, workflow-manager, workflow-designer

We have an interesting case which I think is a bug in WorkflowManager SP2013. Maybe someone has seen it before and has a solution. We had the issue in the VS workflow, but managed to recreate issue in a simple Designer workflow. When a workflow assigns a task to a userName that has an apostrophe (i.e. John.O'Brien), the workflow fails and reports bad request : HTTP BadRequest.

Now the same workflow in SharePoint 2010 works ok.  The task is assigned without problem.

I know that having apostrophe in the username (yes the apostrophe is in both username and display name) is not best practice but it is allowed by AD. 
- We tried escaping the character without success; 
- same issue persists when you try to encode the apostrophe.
We researched and found [the following Technet article about escaping AD characters escaping](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx).  It says that apostrophe is ok.

Has anyone else faced same issue before and managed to resolve it without changes to the AD accounts and policy?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem here. Have you been able to find a solution ?

Comment: Yes and No, we couldn't find the solution, but we managed to convince our Boss to change his loginName and tighten the AD account creation policy. (Display name is ok with the apostrophe in our scenario)